# Unable to create model class instance from retrofit2 reponse generic ApiResponse sealed class

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2

I am implementing MVVM with repository in my application. Created a generic response class and facing exception while trying to create ApiResponse.Success in repository with response received using retrofit2.

**ApiResponse class**

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T> (
    val code: Int? = null,
    val status: String? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
    val data: T? = null,
    val errors: Map<String, ArrayList<String>>? = null,
    val exceptionMessage: String? = null,
) {
    // Loading state
    class Loading<T>: ApiResponse<T>()

    // Success state
    class Success<T> (data: T?): ApiResponse<T> (data = data)

    // Error state
    class Error<T> (errors: Map<String, ArrayList<String>>?): ApiResponse<T> (errors = errors)

    // Runtime Exception
    class ExceptionError<T> (exceptionMessage: String?): ApiResponse<T> (exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage)
}
```

**AuthService Interface**

```
interface AuthService {

    @POST("accounts/login")
    suspend fun getTokenPair(@Body userLoginCred: UserLoginCred): Response<ApiResponse<UserTokenPair>>
}
```

**AuthRepository Code**

```
if (NetworkUtil.isInternetAvailable(context)!!) {
    try {
        val response = authService.getTokenPair(userLoginCred)
        if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            _userTokenPairResponse.postValue(ApiResponse.Success(response.body()!!.data))
        }
        else if (response.errorBody() != null) {
            _userTokenPairResponse.postValue(ApiResponse.Error(Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()!!.string(), Map::class.java) as Map<String, ArrayList<String>>))
        }
        else {
            _userTokenPairResponse.postValue(ApiResponse.Loading())
        }
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        _userTokenPairResponse.postValue(ApiResponse.ExceptionError(e.message))
    }
}
else {
    _userTokenPairResponse.postValue(ApiResponse.ExceptionError("Device not connected to internet."))
}
```

**What is working and what not?**

```
Loading state -> Working
Error state -> working
Execption state -> working
Success state -> always have exception
```

```
Unable to create instance of class com.example.ApiResponse. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor may fix this problem.
```